# Jinja2 filter to convert custom markup to html

Tags: python, filter, escaping, flask, jinja2

Having the **autoescape** property on (I want to keep it that way), I want user to be able to enter some custom markup, to have the opportunity to format text. For example, `[s][/s]` will be translated into `<strong></strong>`. I believe the right way to do this is to write the custom Jinja2 filter. But the following doesn't work:

```
@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def mark2html(eval_ctx, value):
    result = escape(value).replace('[s]','<strong>')
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

When applied to text like

```
<div>{{ custom_markup_text|mark2html }}</div>
```

When `[s]` is encountered in the string, stored in **custom_markup_text**, it should be converted to `<strong>` tag. AFAIK, *Markup()* function ensures that we trust this particular string, so that HTML is not escaped there. The filter is successfully applied, `[s]` is replaced by `<strong>`, but it's still escaped.

Obviously, the autoescaping is done **after** this custom filter. On the other hand, example filter from Jinja2 documentation works perfectly:

```
@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace('\n', '<br>\n') \
        for p in _paragraph_re.split(escape(value)))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem found. It's double escaping the string - rather silly.
This code works flawlessly:

```
@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def mark2html(eval_ctx, value):
    result = value.replace('[s]',u'<strong>')
    result = result.replace('[/s]',u'</strong>')
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

Note, **value** shouldn't be escaped, as autoescape property is on.

Comment: The [concept](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters) behind this. The [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/) it's based on. How to [call within the template](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14595911/1599229).

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar ability to add html tags to highlight/bold certain text in `fastapi` my python code.
I was able to use '**safe**' keyword to allow the `<b> and <br/>` tags to be unescaped.
In this instance col.text contains several lines and each line had distinct bolding and line breaks. I have Jinja2==3.1.2 installed.

```
{% for line in col.text %}
    {{ line | safe }}
{% endfor %}
```