# Unencode a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, list, flask, escaping

Is there a way to convert escape codes back into the characters they represent in javascript?
I am passing a list to a javascript file, and when I look at the source, instead of this

```
['/path/to/job/a', '/path/to/job/b', etc]
```

I am seeing this

```
[&#39;/path/to/job/a&#39;, &#39;/path/to/job/b&#39;, etc]
```

I need the actual single quotes themselves for a jquery autocomplete call, so is there a way to convert back? I am passing the list to the javascript from a python/flask backend

```
return render_template('main_page.html', job_names = id_by_job.keys())
```

So in the javascript file, I am doing something like

```
$("#job_names").autocomplete({source : {{job_names}}});
```

Comment: You need to tell your templating engine to not escape output.

Comment: how to do that? I'm using Flask

Comment: possible duplicate of [disabling autoescape in flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592554/disabling-autoescape-in-flask)

Answer (score 0):

Values interpolated into templates are always escaped for safe inclusion; that includes replacing quotes with HTML entities.

You want to convert your list to JSON here instead using the [`tojson` filter](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templating/#standard-filters), and mark the result as safe:

```
$("#job_names").autocomplete({source : {{ job_names|tojson_safe }}});
```

JSON is a subset of JavaScript; the result is directly readable as JavaScript, guaranteed to be properly escaped.

Answer (score -2):

a neat trick is to use a temporary option:

```
var o=new Option();
o.innerHTML="&#39;/path/to/job/a&#39;, &#39;/path/to/job/b&#39;, etc"
alert(o.innerHTML); // shows: "'/path/to/job/a', '/path/to/job/b', etc"
```

you can also use a RegExp replace with a function callback:

```
"&#39;/path/to/job/a&#39;, &#39;/path/to/job/b&#39;, etc".replace(/&#(\d+);/g,
  function(j,a){
     return String.fromCharCode(a)
  }); // == "'/path/to/job/a', '/path/to/job/b', etc"
```

EDIT:
i realized you probably want to handle arrays, and [].map() makes it easy to apply the above to an array:

```
['/path/to/job/a', '/path/to/job/b']
 .map(function(a){ return a.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(j,a){
      return String.fromCharCode(a)
  });
}); // == ["/path/to/job/a", "/path/to/job/b"]
```

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote and still the autocomplete isn't working. Do you know a way to debug this on IE?

Comment: ie8+ has the [F12] debugger built-in. maybe you need to strip off the apos; the regexp leaves them behind but a simple .slice(1,-1) will remove them if you don't want to match the apos itself (which you don't need to have a valid string after the RegExp is done)...